# Angular ui-grid 3.0: how to handle changes to input defined in a cellTemplate

Tags: event-handling, onchange, angular-ui-grid

I have an Angular 1.4.7 ui-grid 3.0.7 that includes the following column definition:

```
{
  displayName: 'Qty',
  name: 'Quantity',
  width: '10%',
  type: 'number',
  headerCellClass: 'partsListGridHeader',
  cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="!row.groupHeader"><input id="{{row.entity.PartNumber}}" type="number" ng-change="vm.SelectedProduct.IsConfigurationSaved = false;" size="4" ng-maxlength="4" class="partsListQuantity" ng-class="{ \'autoConfigured\': row.entity.IsAutoConfigured }" style="width:50px;" min="{{row.entity.MinValue}}" max="{{row.entity.MaxValue}}" step="1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="row.entity.Quantity" ng-readonly="row.entity.IsAutoConfigured" /></div>',
  aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
}
```

I was counting on the ng-change directive to reset a common dirty property that has a smaller scope than Angular's form.$dirty.  But, ng-change is not supported in cell templates for performance reasons.

What should I use instead?

You can see a simplified version of my code at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FNXLhRIRHQHlxGAehAsH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

After considering Ryan Clark's excellent advice about how to create custom listeners at [How AngularJS implements dirty checking and how to replicate it ourselves](http://ryanclark.me/how-angularjs-implements-dirty-checking/), I decided to take the low road and use Angular's form.$dirty property and live with it's lack of precision.